# How to display data at the end of the month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

How do you display the latest data for a particular month?

**For example I have data like this**

```
  date      data
2003-04-18 | 12
2003-04-25 | 14
2003-05-16 | 51
2003-05-23 | 21
2003-05-30 | 22
2003-06-06 | 11
2003-06-27 | 14
```

**I want to display data**

```
  date      data
2003-04-25 | 14
2003-05-30 | 22
2003-06-27 | 14
```

What kind of example query is used?

i try this query, but showing all data

```
SELECT tgl_hargaemas, harga FROM tbl_hargaemas
WHERE tgl_hargaemas >= '2003-01-03' - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH('2018-01-03') MONTH
```

Comment: First store data using correct formats and data types

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: Just the dates or the entire row?

Comment: showing the entire row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple GROUP BY sub query to find the max date for each year-month followed by an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(date) AS maxdate
    FROM t
    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
) AS g
INNER JOIN t ON g.maxdate = t.date
```

[**Demo on DB<>Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3aaab7d4fa2803b80f2de217af2c6ca)